# Tensorflow access denied in config_util.py while training

Tags: python, tensorflow, access-denied

I have a problem with training a model in `tensorflow`. I am working on Windows 10. When I run the command:

```
python ./object_detection/model_main.py --pipeline_config_path=C:/Tensorflow/object-detection/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2018_01_28 --model_dir=C:/Tensorflow/object-detection/output-model --num_train_steps=50000 --sample_1_of_n_eval_examples=1 --alsologtostderr
```

from `C:/Tensorflow/models/research` to start the training process I get an error in line 95 `(proto_str = f.read())` from the `config_util.py` script. Below 
you can see my whole console output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./object_detection/model_main.py", line 109, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\lucci\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "./object_detection/model_main.py", line 71, in main
    FLAGS.sample_1_of_n_eval_on_train_examples))
  File "C:\Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\model_lib.py", line 536, in create_estimator_and_inputs
    config_override=config_override)
  File "C:\Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\utils\config_util.py", line 95, in get_configs_from_pipeline_file
    proto_str = f.read()
  File "C:\Users\lucci\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 125, in read
    self._preread_check()
  File "C:\Users\lucci\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 85, in _preread_check
    compat.as_bytes(self.__name), 1024 * 512, status)
  File "C:\Users\lucci\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 528, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: C:/Tensorflow/object-detection/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2018_01_28 : Zugriff verweigert
; Input/output error
```

The error is in the last two lines: `Zugriff verweigert` is german and means `access denied`.
I am admin on this pc (it's my own pc) and i have FullControl to the folders (I double-checked it with PowerShell). When I try to move the folder to another
place, e.g. `C:\Users\lucci\Documents\` I get the same error. The problem still remains when I run the console as admin, when I try the command `runas /user:lucci ...` and
so on.

Can anyone help me with this?
I am using Python3.6.

*EDIT:* This also not helps: [Tensorflow Windows Accessing Folders Denied:"NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: Access is denied. ; Input/output error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41116270/tensorflow-windows-accessing-folders-deniednewrandomaccessfile-failed-to-creat)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the solution on my own. It does not matter if you are operating on **Linux** or **Windows**.
When you run the command you always have to specify the **full path to the pipeline.config** file.
So, when your pipeline.config-file is located in `C:/ObjectDetection/Model/pipeline.config` it is not
sufficient to specify the location like `C:/ObjectDetection/`. You have to specify the location
as `C:/ObjectDetection/pipeline.config`.

Running the command again with the **full path for** the Parameter `--pipeline_config_file` works great!!!