# NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: output_inference_graph_v1.pb : Access is denied

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow1.15

**Please read it through.**

This is not a duplicate of [Tensorflow Windows Accessing Folders Denied:"NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: Access is denied. ; Input/output error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41116270/tensorflow-windows-accessing-folders-deniednewrandomaccessfile-failed-to-creat), as I have previously verified if there was an error with my file links and tested it isolated.

The full error output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\rzimm\anaconda3\envs\rapidrzr\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 122, in read
    self._preread_check()
  File "C:\Users\rzimm\anaconda3\envs\rapidrzr\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 84, in _preread_check
    compat.as_bytes(self.__name), 1024 * 512)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17/output_inference_graph_v1.pb : Access is denied.
```

There was no problem in training my model and my Tensorflow installation is working correctly, as I already went through the *Tutorial Notebook*

What is this error and why is it happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have already solved this issue, if anyone happens to be in the same situation, this issue I opened in GitHub contains the solution:

[GitHub/tensorflow/issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/41482)